# Syntax Error: Invalid number, expected digit but got: "t". while passing a slug url to the graphql query function (nextjs app)

Tags: next.js, graphql

I'm having this error while I'm trying to get the right content according to the url. This is my query function:

```js
const getSlugQuery = (slug) => {
  const SLUG_QUERY = gql`
    query ($slug: String!) {
      postCollection(where:{slug:${slug}}) {
        items {
          title
          shortDescription
          heroImg {
            url
          }
          createdAt
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  return SLUG_QUERY;
};
```

my getStaticprops where I pass the context.params.id:

```js
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: getSlugQuery(context.params.id)
  });
```

and the getStaticPath to prerender the cases:

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {

  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: POSTS_QUERY
  });

  const paths = data.postCollection.items.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.slug },
  }))

  return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

If I try to pass an hardcoded url to the query, the response is working. What am I doing wrong there?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to change your implementation to pass variables

Change `getSlugQuery` to not take any parameters:

```js
const getSlugQuery = () => {
  const SLUG_QUERY = gql`
    query ($slug: String!) {
      postCollection(where:{slug:$slug}) {
        items {
          title
          shortDescription
          heroImg {
            url
          }
          createdAt
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  return SLUG_QUERY;
};
```

Then change `getStaticProps` to pass the slug as a variable to the apolloclient:

```js
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: getSlugQuery(),
    variables: {
      slug: context.params.id,
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: I've tried that, but then the slug parameter after the getSlugQuery function declaration will result unused and grey out in the Ide.

Comment: you're right. I've updated my answer to show how you can pass `slug` as a variable

Comment: Thanks so much, variables object inside the staticProps did the trick! I thought I could have use that only inside useQuery